# Storing an Array in a HashMap as its value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I want to store a Float array as a value of the HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, Float[]> vFeatureHm = new HashMap<Integer, Float[]>();
```

The float array here contains a specified number of values, for example say 10. How and where do I mention that ? I will be dynamically adding the values into that array. I can use an ArrayList but I'm using this for a matrix kind structure and it is easy for me to just get the value from the index as the values are stored in that order. ArrayList seems to be an overkill  in this case for me. Can you suggest how to solve this. For now, I started working with ArrayList, but I want to know if there is a way to use as I mentioned above.

Update: I realized ArrayList will not work for me in my case as I need to place in a particular index. So I have to use either the format mentioned above or use a HashMap which is again a over kill. Any suggestions on using Float as above mentioned ?

Comment: Do you just have 1 Float array of 10 values, or multiple such arrays? What is the role of the Integer that you use as a key to the HashMap?

Comment: You should consider using Guava Table: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table

Comment: @PNS I have a list of movieIDs and there are 10 features for each movie. The movieIDs are not in sequential order (say there are 1000 movies, the highest movie ID can be 9338). But all the movies will and must have same 10 features. So the key of the map is a movieID and value is float array of 10 values. I cannot keep this a array list because index is important.

Comment: @OmarHrynkiewicz, thank you for the input. It looks to do as I want, but as I mentioned, I do not want to use Maps as they seem over kill to me. I am trying to find if we can do this with Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify the dimensions of the `Float[]` array.

That array is an `Object` like any other value of the `vFeatureHm` map, so any bounds checking is irrelevant to the `HashMap` (although of course it can be performed at another part of your code).

Comment: thanks. That helped. I missed that Float[] is just another object. I initialized it like below. `Float[] featureValues = uFeatureHm.get(userid);
      if(featureValues == null){
       featureValues = new Float[Settings.noOfCommonFeatures];
       featureValues[fi-1] = fv;
       uFeatureHm.put(userid, featureValues);
      }else{
       featureValues[fi-1] = fv;
      }`

Comment: Assuming that the variables you use in the code above are defined and consistent, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since float is an object, I initialized it like below.

```
Float[] featureValues = uFeatureHm.get(userid);
if(featureValues == null){
    featureValues = new Float[Settings.noOfCommonFeatures];
    featureValues[fi-1] = fv;
    uFeatureHm.put(userid, featureValues);
}else{
    featureValues[fi-1] = fv;
}
```

Later, I can simply access a feature of particular user as `uFeatureHm.get(userid)[featureIndex]`